# Inject angular module using $ocLazyLoad.inject method

Tags: angularjs, oclazyload

Trying to inject an Angular module to my main module using oclazyload. Please note, I am not using RequireJs or oclazyload to load the JavaScript file currently.
For now I added the module inside Index HTML Script tag.

The inject method executes without any error. But when I log $ocLazyLoad.getModules(), I don't see the module I wanted to inject.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Inline Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var app = angular.module("ngNextGenWidget", []); //This is the module to be injected
    app.factory('nextGenWidget', function () {
        return {
            constructControl: function ($compile, $scope) {
                //Compile html fragment
                var compileFunction = $compile("<div tools-Home-Page></div>")

                //Get html output from directive after applying $scope
                var htmloutputFromDirective = compileFunction($scope);
                return htmloutputFromDirective;
            }
        }
    });

    app.directive('toolsHomePage', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: true,
            templateUrl: '/Content/Templates/DemoTemplate-1.html',
            controller: ['$scope', function ($scope) {
                $scope.name = 'Home Page';
            }]
        }
    });

</script>
```

Main app:

```
appLazy.directive('testComponent', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.Execute(attrs, element, attrs.moduleName);
        },
        controller: ['$scope', '$compile', '$ocLazyLoad',
            function ($scope, $compile, $ocLazyLoad) {
            $scope.Execute = function (attr, element, moduleName) {
                $ocLazyLoad.inject(moduleName);//trying to inject the module
                var htmloutputFromDirective =
                    $nextGenWidget.constructControl($compile, $scope);
                $(element).append(htmloutputFromDirective);
            }

        }]
    };
});
```